# Installing Intel x86 in windows for Android is Failing

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to install Intel x86 in my windows laptop and it is failing with the error message. Attached is the screenshot:
[image]

Could you please help me how to solve this issue? Without this, AVD is not working at all.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

With regards,
Sudipta Deb

Comment: Did you try to redownload it? Maybe that was just a temporal problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also download it manually from this [link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/android). See Tools and Download at Intel page.

You should also retry first to download using SDK Manager. If still not working then go for manually.